# Get rid of white space/margin in bookmarks

Tags: adobe-acrobat

I just started using Adobe Acrobat version 2022.001.20085 (64-bit).

Now in bookmarks, there's this additional weird white space/margin to the left of each bookmark (didn't exist in previous versions of Acrobat I've used).

This white space/margin takes up space. How do I get rid of it?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried dragging the bar with the ◀ symbol to the left?

Comment: @DavidPostill: Yes (same amount of white space no matter what)

Comment: Do the help pages of the program reference it at all? If Adobe puts out a changelog, have you checked that? You may want to reach out to Adobe directly if no one posts an answer.